# Crear condicion

Tags: php, laravel

Tengo esta función en donde hay otras mas de un formulario

```
$valorasociado = new RadicadosAsociado();
$valorasociado->RasRadicados = $id;
$valorasociado->RasRadcadoAsociado = $request['RasRadcadoAsociado'];
$valorasociado->save();
```

Quiero que se ejecute al recibir un valor si no NULL pase al otro.
 se el concepto de condiciones `if` pero hasta ahora voy a implementarlo, no se como.

Comment: A que te refieres con que pase al otro y que es lo que quieres validar que no sea null???

Comment: en el formulario habrá a veces que no se ingresara valores entonces pase al otro se refiere es que continué con la siguiente función. porque cuando el corre todo y las columnas de la base de datos de llenan null

Comment: Porque no pones la funcion completa y explicas mas detalladamente que intentas hacer para poder ayudarte mejor.